# How do I develop a web page that returns password for users to register?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am doing a project on creating a lab application for a next generation sequencing data using ruby on rails.

The main idea my boss suggests me to do is to have users fill in their details and submit to us. After the submission, the administrator, i.e. me, would send them a password which they can use to login my application. could some one help me with the idea of development. I am naive to ruby on rails and would be very grateful for people who help me.

thank you and cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with [Michael Hartl's RailsTutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/). Not only did I find it the best way to get started - the application he builds includes a bombproof user security model, just as you require, and so you'd be both learning and developing something relevant at the same time.

I'd also recommend buying the videos, as well as the book. They make all the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Are you new to the whole web development thing or is it just Ruby on rails that you have no knowledge of?

If the former, I'd suggest googling some Ruby tutorials on how to make a simple web application and build from there. Start by a simple "Hello world" application, then proceed to handle submitted forms, then install and use a database and by then you should have the basic knowledge to build what you want.

If the latter, could you specify, what parts you need help with? Ruby is syntactically quite easy to learn if you just take a look at some tutorials, so that shouldn't pose any problems. You have described a simple use case which I'm sure you can handle in a new environment, if you just have the patience to try and learn.

Comment: I am the latter, and I am trying to figure out the difference. Thanks for the suggestions and will post new things as I go along the development.?